# Problem booting Ubuntu (Failure reading sector 0x.. from hd0)

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.5 on my ASUS R558U laptop. The installation completed after setting boot parameters. I used the erase disk option so I have only Ubuntu on my laptop.

But when I try to boot Ubuntu from the grub menu. It shows the message-

```
"Environment block too small"
"failure reading sector 0x.. from 'hd0' "
```

and does not proceed from here.

From a live USB I have done the following-

SMART indicates health of disk is OK.

I have reinstalled grub as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

I ran Boot-Repair, but that also didn't fix the problem. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kNKMQ9h8QK/) is the log.

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance !